# Issue in adding google Analytics to iOS

Tags: ios5, google-analytics, xcode4.3

After adding the libGoogleAnalytics.a CFNetwork and libsqlite3.0.dylib frameworks, and added the GANTracker.h into my AppDelegate.m

I get this error:

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GANTracker", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
and the app won't even compile. My app is aimed at iOS 5.0

Comment: did you solve above error?